# Reference wind directions to texture space?

Tags: java, c#, coding

I have a 2D array filled with a simple class:

```
class Tile
{
    boolean N,E,S,W;
}
```

I also have a tilesheet representing all possible outcomes except all false (12 + crossroad). Now i need to reference all these possibilities to texture space on my sheet. Apart from having an if statement for each and every outcome is there a more efficient way i cannot currently think off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are doing here, but your class looks to be equivalent to a 4-bit integer and so it might be helpful to return its state as such -- or even better, as a bit flag enum.  It might also be useful to introduce an indexer property to your class (I'm using c# here) to iterate easily through the values in the 4 cardinal directions:

```
public enum CardinalDirection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The +Y Direction 
    /// </summary>
    N = (1 << 0),
    /// <summary>
    /// The +X Direction 
    /// </summary>
    E = (1 << 1),
    /// <summary>
    /// The -Y Direction
    /// </summary>
    S = (1 << 2),
    /// <summary>
    /// The -X Direction
    /// </summary>
    W = (1 << 3),
}

[Flags]
public enum Direction
{
    None = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// The +Y Direction 
    /// </summary>
    N = (1 << 0),
    /// <summary>
    /// The +X Direction 
    /// </summary>
    E = (1 << 1),
    /// <summary>
    /// The -Y Direction
    /// </summary>
    S = (1 << 2),
    /// <summary>
    /// The -X Direction
    /// </summary>
    W = (1 << 3),

    NE = N + E,
    NS = N + S,
    NW = N + W,
    ES = E + S,
    EW = E + W,
    SW = S + W,

    NES = N + E + S,
    NEW = N + E + W,
    NSW = N + S + W,
    ESW = E + S + W,

    NESW = N + E + S + W
}

public class Tile
{
    bool N, E, S, W;

    public static Direction ToDirection(bool N, bool E, bool S, bool W)
    {
        Direction dir = Direction.None;
        if (N)
            dir |= Direction.N;
        if (E)
            dir |= Direction.E;
        if (S)
            dir |= Direction.S;
        if (W)
            dir |= Direction.W;
        return dir;
    }

    public static void FromDirection(Direction dir, out bool N, out bool E, out bool S, out bool W)
    {
        N = (dir & Direction.N) == Direction.N;
        E = (dir & Direction.E) == Direction.E;
        S = (dir & Direction.S) == Direction.S;
        W = (dir & Direction.W) == Direction.W;
    }

    public Direction Direction
    {
        get
        {
            return Tile.ToDirection(N, E, S, W);
        }

        set
        {
            Tile.FromDirection(value, out N, out E, out S, out W);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the the value in the specified direction
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dir"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool this[CardinalDirection cardinalDirection]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (cardinalDirection)
            {
                case CardinalDirection.N:
                    return N;
                case CardinalDirection.E:
                    return E;
                case CardinalDirection.S:
                    return S;
                case CardinalDirection.W:
                    return W;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dir", cardinalDirection.ToString());
            }
        }
        set
        {
            switch (cardinalDirection)
            {
                case CardinalDirection.N:
                    N = value;
                    return;
                case CardinalDirection.E:   
                    E = value;
                    return;
                case CardinalDirection.S:
                    S = value;
                    return;
                case CardinalDirection.W:
                    W = value;
                    return;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dir", cardinalDirection.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should allow you to conveniently switch on selected combinations of directions.

As an example of using the indexer property to iterate through the cardinal direction flags, the following method, given a 2d array of tiles, counts the number of tiles adjacent to a specified tile with matching flag values:

```
public static class TileHelper
{
    public static int CountConsistent(Tile[][] tiles, int iX, int iY)
    {
        int count = 0;
        var tile = tiles[iX][iY];
        foreach (var pair in tiles.WalkAround(iX, iY))
        {
            var dir = pair.Key;
            if (tile[dir] == pair.Value[dir.Rotate180()])
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enumerate through the 4 tiles N, E, S, and W of the given tile in the tile array.
    /// Tiles off the edges of the array will be skipped.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tiles"></param>
    /// <param name="iX"></param>
    /// <param name="iY"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<CardinalDirection, Tile>> WalkAround(this Tile[][] tiles, int iX, int iY)
    {
        if (iX < 0 || iY < 0 || iX >= tiles.Length || iY >= tiles[iX].Length)
            yield break;
        if (iY + 1 < tiles[iX].Length)
            yield return new KeyValuePair<CardinalDirection, Tile>(CardinalDirection.N, tiles[iX][iY + 1]);
        if (iX + 1 < tiles.Length)
            yield return new KeyValuePair<CardinalDirection, Tile>(CardinalDirection.E, tiles[iX + 1][iY]);
        if (iY > 1)
            yield return new KeyValuePair<CardinalDirection, Tile>(CardinalDirection.S, tiles[iX][iY - 1]);
        if (iX > 1)
            yield return new KeyValuePair<CardinalDirection, Tile>(CardinalDirection.W, tiles[iX - 1][iY]);
    }

    public static CardinalDirection Rotate180(this CardinalDirection cardinalDirection)
    {
        switch (cardinalDirection) {
            case CardinalDirection.N:
                return CardinalDirection.S;
            case CardinalDirection.E:
                return CardinalDirection.W;
            case CardinalDirection.S:
                return CardinalDirection.N;
            case CardinalDirection.W:
                return CardinalDirection.E;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dir", cardinalDirection.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

(Probably the first method could be done more beautifully with Linq).

Hope that helps.

Comment: If it is a 4-bit integer, why introduce an integer at all (minimum is a byte with 8bits)? Wouldn't 4 boolean like asked be better suited?

Comment: @randomA: I didn't remove the 4 booleans in the class, they're still there.  I just exposed their current values in a single bitmask enum.  For some reason the original poster found it inconvenient to work with 4 separate booleans via complex "if" statements -- something like "if (N && !E && S && !W)".  The enum could be used, e.g., in switch statements or as some index key into a resource file.  But we really don't know why the original poster was unhappy with keeping 4 independent booleans; perhaps he could comment?

Comment: ok, I got what you mean.